# Best ERROR RESPONSE I should send from Server to Android?

Tags: android, server, httpresponse

I am developing a communication's system between an Android App and a Server.

I am using Retrofit API for the Android's communication with the Server.

When I do a GET (from Android side) to *get* info from the Server, I use a CallBackTask method like this:

```
 public void testGet()
{

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(UserApi.SERVER)
            .build();
    final UserApi svc = restAdapter.create(UserApi.class);


    if (svc != null) {
        CallableTask.invoke(new Callable<Test>() {

            @Override
            public Test call() throws Exception {


                Test g = svc.getTest();
                     System.out.println("getVdd() = "+g.getVdd()+"+ getResp() = "+g.getResp());
                return g;
            }
        }, new TaskCallback<Test>() {

            @Override
            public void success(Test result) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashRapidoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void error(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Unable to connect, please try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Where the `Test.class` is a POJO class with variables and his getters and setters:

```
public class Test {

String vdd;
String resp;

public Test()
{
}

public void setVdd(String vdd) {
    this.vdd = vdd;
}

public String getVdd() {
    return vdd;
}
public void setResp(String resp)
{}
public String getResp()
{
    return resp;
}
}
```

So, my question is, which is the best *ERROR RESPONSE* i could send from the server if there aren't valid values for the Test.class in the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no "the best error response". It depends on your requirements. But there is widely used architecture called `REST` and `Retrofit` was designed in according with `REST` interaction. `REST` basically is just a set of rules which `clients` and `servers` understand without any documentation.

So if you want to retrieve(`GET`) some object/data from server by `REST` you can either receive it with status `200` or receive status `404` with appropriate description of error(or without it) inside body.

[Here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) some more to read.

Answer (score 1):

The best error response is one that make sense to you as a developer. I wouldn't mess with the default HTTP status/error codes. Instead I would send a specific response from the server. For example, keep the HTTP response code at 200 but in the data you send to the app set it to "ERROR: no values." or whatever you prefer. Then, in your Android app, check the response to see if it contains values or an error. Something like

```
if(resp.startsWith("ERROR:")){
    // Do error handling //
} else { 
    // Normal code //
}
```